# similar functionality like uitableview in iphone to in android?

Tags: android

can anybody please give me example of using similar functionality like uitableview in iphone to in android?

Comment: What is uitableview? Please do not assume that Android developers are expert on other platforms. Use a screenshot or something to explain what it is you are seeking.

Comment: This link is useful for UITable view in android. http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/12/iphone-uitable-view-in-android.html

Comment: Not sure if you still need it, but i have created a android library for that. Check this out [UITableView for Android](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview)

Answer (score 13):

UITableView's equivalent is ListView

Have a look at this thread for an example:

[Implementing "Drilldown" navigation in Android App UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958560/beginner-best-practices-in-an-android-app-ui-navagation/2959594#2959594)

Comment: It's not a close equivalent though.